# Images in table do not align, even with cellpadding="0"

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a couple of images inside of a table (it's for an email so I've had to use tables) that are not aligning even once I have used `cellpadding=0`. Any ideas?

```
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
  <td cellpadding="0" colspan="5"><img src="http://www.tradetech.net/images/Holidayemail/tt_holiday_boat_23_01.gif" alt="" width="444" height="43" /></td>
</tr>
<tr cellpadding="0">
  <td cellpadding="0" rowspan="4"><img src="http://www.tradetech.net/images/Holidayemail/tt_holiday_boat_23_02.gif" alt="" width="46" height="252" /></td>
  <td cellpadding="0" colspan="3"><img src="http://www.tradetech.net/images/Holidayemail/boxes.gif" alt="" width="296" height="142" /></td>
  <td cellpadding="0" rowspan="4"><img src="http://www.tradetech.net/images/Holidayemail/tt_holiday_boat_23_04.gif" alt="" width="102" height="252" /></td>
</tr>
<tr cellpadding="0">
  <td cellpadding="0" colspan="3"><img src="http://www.tradetech.net/images/Holidayemail/tt_holiday_boat_23_05.gif" alt="" width="296" height="33" /></td>
</tr>
<tr cellpadding="0">
  <td cellpadding="0" rowspan="2"><img src="http://www.tradetech.net/images/Holidayemail/tt_holiday_boat_23_06.gif" alt="" width="32" height="77" /></td>
  <td cellpadding="0"><img src="http://www.tradetech.net/images/Holidayemail/greeting.gif" alt="" width="151" height="29" /></td>
  <td cellpadding="0" rowspan="2"><img src="http://www.tradetech.net/images/Holidayemail/tt_holiday_boat_23_08.gif" alt="" width="113" height="77" /></td>
</tr>
<tr cellpadding="0">
  <td cellpadding="0"><img src="http://www.tradetech.net/images/Holidayemail/tt_holiday_boat_23_09.gif" alt="" width="151" height="48" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cellpadding does not do anything on the  tag as stated above, since you are creating a HTML e-mail you need to set the width on the  tags to not allow any room to move around. Just adding images doesn't help.

I've created a fiddle where the images in your layout line up perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/Scopestyle/6Qva2/

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
```

```
    <table width="444" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><img style="display: block;" src="http://placehold.it/444x43" alt="" width="444" height="43" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="46" rowspan="3" valign="top"><img style="display: block;" src="http://placehold.it/46x252" alt="" width="46" height="252" /></td>
        <td width="296"><img style="display: block;" src="http://placehold.it/296x142" alt="" width="296" height="142" /></td>
        <td width="102" rowspan="3" valign="top"><img style="display: block;" src="http://placehold.it/102x252" alt="" width="102" height="252" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img style="display: block;" src="http://placehold.it/296x33" alt="" width="296" height="33" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="296" valign="top">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="32" rowspan="2"><img style="display: block;" src="http://placehold.it/32x77" alt="" width="32" height="77" /></td>
                <td width="151"><img style="display: block;" src="http://placehold.it/151x29" alt="" width="151" height="29" /></td>
                <td width="113" rowspan="2"><img style="display: block;" src="http://placehold.it/113x77" alt="" width="113" height="77" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="151"><img style="display: block;" src="http://placehold.it/151x48" alt="" width="151" height="48" /></td>
              </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

</td>
```

If you look at the code notice a few tricks I've used to make it work:

1. The HTML is nested in tables. This makes complicated cell layouts easier to manage and less likely to break.
2. All cells have the width of the images, so we don't allow gaps between the cells.
3. The images have inline styles with the display: block; attribute. This neutralizes any gaps below the image that could occur in different browsers and e-mail clients.

When testing your e-mail code, putsmail.com is a handy tool to see what it looks like in your inbox. When debugging different e-mail clients take a look at emailology.org for interesting tips.

Answer (score 2):

cellpadding="0" belongs inside the `<table>` tag, not the `<td>` tag or the `<tr>` tag.

Comment: Ralph is correct. If you want to remove padding per TD/TR, use the CSS property `padding: 0;`

Answer (score 1):

wow I can't even imagine what you're trying to do but to remove most of the spacing add this to the `<table>` tag:

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
```